# hide element press Esc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, hide

This code doesn't hide the box `div` which was supposed to be hidden when I press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

```
function Boxup(elementN, event){
    $("#"+elementN).css({
        "display":"block",
        "top":event.pageY+"px" ,
        "left":event.pageX+"px"    
    })
}
function hideCurrentPopup(ele){
    $(ele).parent().hide();
}

    $(this).keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 27) { 
            disablePopup();  
        }   
    });
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: In your example, when the esc key is pressed, you call "disablePopup" but there is no disablePopup in your example?

Comment: Also, escape key seems to be tied to `this` ... is it inside some other code or did you want to tie to something like `"body"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I cannot exactly tell what's `this` referring to in this line:

```
$(this).keyup(function(event) {
```

cause it `this` refers to a `"textarea"` or `"input"` it will trigger the event **if that element has *focus***, otherwise you're looking for `keyup` events registered by `document`

but here's what you can try.

```
function Boxup(elementN, event){
    $("#"+elementN).css({
        display : "block",
        top  : event.pageY , // px are not needed as they are default unit in jQ
        left : event.pageX    
    })
}

function hideCurrentPopup(ele){ // note your function name and the argument! 
    $(ele).parent().hide();     // (do you need .parent()? I don't know
}                               // without seeing any HTML sample)

$(document).keyup(function(event) { // document is probably the selector you want
    if (event.which == 27) { 
        hideCurrentPopup("#hereYourPopupID");  // try alike
    }   
});
```

<sub>P.S: Make sure that by using `$(some Selector here).keyup(function(event) {` you're not preventing in any case a `keyup` event to bubble up the DOM tree to reach the `documentElement`</sub>